# Index iteration idiom

Tags: r, iteration, idioms

The following code is commonly seen on SO when it comes to iterating over the index values of a collection:

```
for (i in 1:length(x)) {
  # ...
}
```

The code misbehaves when the collection is empty because `1:length(x)` becomes `1:0` which gives `i` the values `1` and `0`.

```
iterate <- function(x) {
    for (i in 1:length(x)) {
      cat('x[[', i, ']] is', x[[i]], '\n')
    }
}

> iterate(c(1,2,3))
x[[ 1 ]] is 1 
x[[ 2 ]] is 2 
x[[ 3 ]] is 3 

> iterate(c())
x[[ 1 ]] is  
x[[ 0 ]] is
```

I recall seeing an elegant idiom for defining a sequence that has no elements when `x` is empty but I cannot remember it. What idiom do you use?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Either `seq` or `seq_along` give you something more reasonable when your object of interest is empty.

```
> x <- NULL
> seq(x)
integer(0)
> seq_along(x)
integer(0)
> x <- rnorm(5)
> seq(x)
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
> seq_along(x)
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: Perfect, `seq_along` was the idiom I saw.

Comment: But if you don't need the index variable and just want to loop over the elements of something, one of lapply/sapply/vapply or something from the plyr package might be more elegant.

Comment: @Spacedman Very true and it's definitely something the OP should keep in mind.